# Terminating app due to uncaught exception on ipad/iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm getting a crash from this routine (IBAction)curr:(id)sender. 
So I could determine which button called it. 
The crash occurs when i press the button which calls the above method(curr). 
It has to display current user location eventually it does but it crashes immediately after showing latitude and longitude.
received data as string

```
{
Error = "Lat must be provided";
Success = 0;
}
```

It throws exception:`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e20000'`

Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)curr:(id)sender
{
count=0;
NSLog(@"fhfg");
NSLog(@"%@",latu);
NSLog(@"%@",longs);
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
if (count==0)
{
int degrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
double decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude - degrees);
int minutes = decimal * 60;
double seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60; 
latu= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", degrees, minutes, seconds];
    //a=latu;
NSLog(@" Current Latitude : %@",latu);
//latLabel.text = lat;
degrees = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude - degrees);
minutes = decimal * 60;
seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
longs = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", degrees, minutes, seconds];
NSLog(@" Current Longitude : %@",longs);
}
}
```

Comment: Learn to set breakpoints in your code and use the debugging tools provided by XCode. They are there for a reason. They will help you. You will be able to solve problems like this yourself. Why are there so many questions being posted on SO where people haven't even made a basic attempt at using these debugging tools?

Comment: yes exactly...set break points and find where is that shit

Answer (score 0):

you can check your .xib file and check first responder by right click on first responder cube symbol.
IF there is any warning symbol in first responder connect outlets than that is the reason for your application crash.